# How do i convert my array from ["1","2","3","4"] to [1,2,3,4]?

Tags: javascript, arrays

i am trying to use the following line block of code

```
var myarray = [1,2,3,4];
var new_array = [];
myarray.reduce(function(a,b,i) { return new_array[i] = a+b; },0);
// Result = [1, 3, 6, 10]
console.log("original array");
console.log(new_array);
```

this block works perfectly but when i substitute my own array the result goes is completely wrong

```
var ar1 = ["1","2","3","4"];
var ar2 = [];
ar1.reduce(function(a,b,i) { return ar2[i] = a+b; },0);
// result = ["01", "012", "0123", "01234"]
console.log("original array");
console.log(ar2);
```

i get this as my result ["01", "012", "0123", "01234"]

Can anyone help, thanks

Comment: don't use reduce. use `map`.

Comment: Or use `.map(Number)` first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `parseInt` to convert `Number` to `String` before using `+` operator. `String + String` is string concatenation, while `Number + Number` is algebraic addition

```
var ar1 = ["1","2","3","4"];
var ar2 = [];
ar1.reduce(function(a,b,i) { return ar2[i] = parseInt(a) + parseInt(b); },0);
// result = ["01", "012", "0123", "01234"]
console.log("original array");
console.log(ar2);
```